# Set up classroom environment to teach PHP using Azure

Tags: php, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have been granted an Microsoft Azure Educator Grant Award.  This fall I am going to teach my PHP course using Azure. I have done this using USB drives. I have done this using VMs in our local cloud.  I have taught it using Amazon WorkSpaces. Instead of having my students set up their development environment on their local machines, I want to create VMs for them and then have them use those VMs to develop, this way they can get to their development environment from anywhere and I can control the environment to ensure consistency.
Has anyone set up something like this using limited Azure resources?
Does anyone have any advice for me as I move forward?

Comment: Why have you tagged your question as related to the VMS family of operating systems?

Comment: That was supposed to be for VMs, as in virtual machines.

Comment: I just removed it.  I was not aware of the connection.

Comment: Unfortunately this is off-topic, as it's really broad and opinion-soliciting. There's no right answer - only suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can leverage Azure Resource Manager template to deploy VMs with the same configurations and resources you set in the template every time to your students.

For basic concepts of ARM, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-overview/.

You can create and configure your model VM in a resource group and export the ARM template, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-export-template/ for details.

And you can modify your templates before deploy to Azure, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-customize-template/ for more info.

At lase, here is a [template sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/templates/lamp-app/) provided by a community, which can deploy a Lamp ubuntu VM on Azure. You also can find for templates provided by communities at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/templates/?term=lamp